# Conditional WHERE clause using a mapping table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like below:

1.**MAPPING** -

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Mapping ID`**</kbd>
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`P01`</kbd>       
<kbd>`A03`</kbd>       <kbd>`P03`</kbd>

2.**MAIN** -

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Metric1`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`Metric2`**</kbd>   
<kbd>`A01`</kbd>       <kbd>`(null)`</kbd>    <kbd>`4.22`</kbd>      
<kbd>`A02`</kbd>       <kbd>`(null)`</kbd>    <kbd>`(null)`</kbd>    
<kbd>`A03`</kbd>       <kbd>`145`</kbd>       <kbd>`127`</kbd>       
<kbd>`A04`</kbd>       <kbd>`(null)`</kbd>    <kbd>`20`</kbd>        
<kbd>`P01`</kbd>       <kbd>`68`</kbd>        <kbd>`(null)`</kbd>    
<kbd>`P03`</kbd>       <kbd>`(null)`</kbd>    <kbd>`(null)`</kbd>

I have to run query for a particular ID. But I have to check two conditions :

> If that ID exists in **MAPPING** table and if one of the Metrics is null
> then I have to take Metric value of the Mapping ID.

- Suppose for A01 , it exists in **MAPPING** and **Metric1** is null so we have to take the value of **Metric1** of **P01** i.e. **68**. But for **Metric2** as it is not null so
  we don't have to consider **P01**.
- Now suppose for **A02** , it is not in the table **MAPPING** . So we will
  show as it is.

I am using **Oracle**. Can you please help me how to make an efficient query for this ?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
SQL> with
  2  mapping (id, mapping_id) as
  3    (select 'A01', 'P01' from dual union all
  4     select 'A03', 'P03' from dual
  5    ),
  6  main (id, metric1, metric2) as
  7    (select 'A01', null, 4.22 from dual union all
  8     select 'A02', null, null from dual union all
  9     select 'A03',  145,  127 from dual union all
 10     select 'A04', null,   20 from dual union all
 11     select 'P01',   68, null from dual union all
 12     select 'P03', null, null from dual
 13    )
 14  select n.id,
 15    case when n.metric1 is null then x.metric1 else n.metric1 end metric1,
 16    case when n.metric2 is null then x.metric2 else n.metric2 end metric2
 17  from main n left join mapping g on n.id = g.id
 18              left join main x on x.id = g.mapping_id
 19  order by n.id;

ID     METRIC1    METRIC2
--- ---------- ----------
A01         68       4,22
A02
A03        145        127
A04                    20
P01         68
P03

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider query that uses Main twice, joined to each field of Mapping:

```
SELECT Main.ID, IIf([Main].[Metric1] Is Null,[Main_1].[Metric1],Main.Metric1) AS M1, 
IIf([Main].[Metric2] Is Null,[Main_1].[Metric2],Main.Metric2) AS M2
FROM Main AS Main_1 
RIGHT JOIN (Main LEFT JOIN Mapping ON Main.ID = Mapping.ID) 
ON Main_1.ID = Mapping.MappingID;
```